# How to parse this JSON string into 2 List<String>

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have some problem to understand how you parse this JSON string.
As seen we have 2 lists in the JSON string. "bids" and "asks"

For bids for example we have:
**0.035314,25.986

0.035313,6.947

etc**

The goals is to create 2 lists, bids and asks where each element in the list contains the above. For example each index contains this information then: "0.035314,25.986" etc.
How will one approach this string when doing this?

Expected output should be as an understanding like below:

```
List<String> bidsLIST = new List<String>();
List<String> asksLIST = new List<String>();
bidsLIST.Add("0.035314,25.986");
bidsLIST.Add("0.035313,6.947");

asksLIST .Add("0.035319,1.139");
asksLIST .Add("0.03532,28.381");
```

JSON is located here:
https://pastebin.com/j6Xckh49

```
{"bids":[[0.035314,25.986],[0.035313,6.947],[0.035312,17.441],[0.035308,4],[0.0353,6.188]],"asks":[[0.035319,1.139],[0.03532,28.381],[0.035324,6.7],[0.035329,2.307],[0.03533,6.868]],"nonce":451939443}
```

This code is not entirely correct:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
void testparseJSON()
{
    String responseBody = "{" +
                            '"' + "bids" + '"' + ":[[0.035314,25.986],[0.035313,6.947],[0.035312,17.441],[0.035308,4],[0.0353,6.188]]," +
                            '"' + "asks" + '"' + ":[[0.035319,1.139],[0.03532,28.381],[0.035324,6.7],[0.035329,2.307],[0.03533,6.868]]," +
                            '"' + "nonce" + '"' + ":451939443}";
    var deserializedTickers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<List<String>, bidsasks>>(responseBody);
    foreach (var bidsasks in deserializedTickers)
    {
        var Bids = bidsasks.Value.bids;
        var Asks = bidsasks.Value.asks;
        if (Bids != null && Asks != null)
        {
            //How to get the 2 lists here?
        }
    }
}
public class bidsasks
{
    public List<String> bids { get; set; }
    public List<String> asks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Look at your Json object. It does not have keys of type `List<String>` (obviously). The values of each key in your Json object are lists of lists with (floating point) numbers, which obviously don't match your `bisasks` class at all. You will have to follow the structure of the Json data when and use and/or create classes/types that match this structure when trying to deserialize the data. You cannot just create and use some class of unrelated structure and hope the deserializer guesses your intention...

Comment: If you need help parsing JSON it really helps if you post the JSON, not code that concatenates strings to build JSON.

Comment: Yes I edited the post with expected output and posted the JSON to in the pastebin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an intermediate class to reflect the JSON structure:

```
public class JsonBidsAsks {
    public List<List<string>> bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> asks { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can parse the JSON and convert to the desired structure:

```
var deserializedTicker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonBidsAsks>(responseBody);
var ans = new bidsasks {
    bids = deserializedTicker.bids.Select(ba => ba.Join(",")).ToList(),
    asks = deserializedTicker.asks.Select(aa => aa.Join(",")).ToList(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    void testparseJSON(){

 String responseBody = "{" +
                                        '"' + "bids" + '"' + ":[[0.035314,25.986],[0.035313,6.947],[0.035312,17.441],[0.035308,4],[0.0353,6.188]]," +
                                        '"' + "asks" + '"' + ":[[0.035319,1.139],[0.03532,28.381],[0.035324,6.7],[0.035329,2.307],[0.03533,6.868]]," +
                                        '"' + "nonce" + '"' + ":451939443}";

                var jsnAsObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responseBody);
                var bids = jsnAsObj.bids;
                var asks = jsnAsObj.asks;
}
```

and put at another class (recommended at a new *.cs file) your DM.
this is just a suggestion and not a must, the code can work as an inner class inside of your current one, but it's not recommended.

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public float[][] bids { get; set; }
        public float[][] asks { get; set; }
        public int nonce { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Yes thank you then I understand. I could make it work with this code. So you put float[][] because it is a commaseparated argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your json to anonymous type:

```
var template = new
{
    bids = new[]
    {
        new[] {1.0, 1.0}
    },
    asks = new[]
    {
        new[] {1.0, 1.0}
    },
};

var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(responseBody, template);
```

Now just join `bids` and `asks` in two lists:

```
var bidsLIST = parsedJson.bids.Select(b => string.Join(",", b)).ToList();
var asksLIST = parsedJson.asks.Select(a => string.Join(",", a)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking the @NetMage answer, I manipulated a little that code and Works without problems.

```
public class bidsasks
{
    public List<List<string>> bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> asks { get; set; }
    public int nonce { get; set; }

}
public static void testparseJSON()
{
    String responseBody = "{" +
                    '"' + "bids" + '"' + ":[[0.035314,25.986],[0.035313,6.947],[0.035312,17.441],[0.035308,4],[0.0353,6.188]]," +
                    '"' + "asks" + '"' + ":[[0.035319,1.139],[0.03532,28.381],[0.035324,6.7],[0.035329,2.307],[0.03533,6.868]]," +
                    '"' + "nonce" + '"' + ":451939443}";
        var deserializedTicker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bidsasks>(responseBody);
        var ans = new bidsasks
        {
            bids = deserializedTicker.bids,
            asks = deserializedTicker.asks
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.bids.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("PRICE", ans.bids[i][0]));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("QTY", ans.bids[i][1]));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.asks.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("PRICE", ans.asks[i][0]));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("QTY", ans.asks[i][1]));
        }
    }
}
```