# How to extract those values from the JSON string

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have this JSON string but are not sure how I will parse out the values that are inside:
**has

has2**

I do succeed to parse out the "id" correctly but are not sure how to access:
**CORS

CORS2

CORS3

CORS4**

I get the error:
**'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])**

I have pasted the JSON in the pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/iWgGV9VK

The code I have:

```
public void getInfo()
{
    String JSONstring = "{ id: 'hello', name: 'Hello',has:{ CORS: false,CORS2: true},has2:{ CORS3: false,CORS4: true}}"; 
    String id = ""; List<String> has = new List<String>(); List<String> has2 = new List<String>();

    var deserializedTicker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonInfo>(JSONstring);
    id = deserializedTicker.id; 
    has = deserializedTicker.has.ToList();
    has2 = deserializedTicker.has.ToList();
}

public class JsonInfo
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String[] has { get; set; }
    public String[] has2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying with the dynamic approach using an object but gets an error here also:

**''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'id''**

```js
//responseBody holds the JSON string
            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
            foreach (var info in stuff)
            {   
                dynamic id = info.Value.id; //''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'id''
                dynamic has = info.Value.has;
                dynamic has2 = info.Value.has2;
                if (has != null && has2 != null)
                {
                    dynamic cors = has.CORS;
                    if(cors != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(cors.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The JSON string both in your code snippet and in your pastebin link isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but the second deserialize(has2) has incorrect.

Comment: Well, look at my comment to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010495/how-to-parse-this-json-string-into-2-liststring from a few hours ago. That comment applies here too. You are here kinda repeating your mistake(s)...

Comment: has and has2 are not strings or arrays of settings, they're complex objects and you'll need to deserislise them as such, or use dynamic or JObject

Comment: I reformatted your code block.  Since this is C# (and not javascript)  you need to use the icon with the { }  symbol on it to format your code, not the one that formats it as javascript.

Comment: Just paste the JSON into your question; there's no reason to make people go to another site.

Comment: I have edit my post with a new approach using dynamic and object but get this error: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'id''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358493/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-into-type-sy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's correct your JSON:

```
{ 
  "id": "hello", 
  "name": "Hello",
  "has": { 
    "CORS": false,
    "CORS2": true
  },
  "has2": { 
    "CORS3": false,
    "CORS4": true
  }
}
```

Now, the problem you are experiencing is because you are attempting to deserialize the value in `"has"` and `"has2"` as arrays. In the JSON, they are not arrays; they are objects. As such, you need to define new classes with the same properties so the JSON can be properly deserialized:

```
public class JsonInfo 
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public JsonHasInfo has { get; set; }
  public JsonHas2Info has2 { get; set; }
}

public class JsonHasInfo
{
  public bool CORS { get; set; }
  public bool CORS2 { get; set; }
}

public class JsonHas2Info
{
  public bool CORS3 { get; set; }
  public bool CORS4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you should be able to deserialize the (correct) JSON properly:

```
String JSONstring = "{ \"id\": \"hello\", \"name\": \"Hello\", \"has\": { \"CORS\": false, \"CORS2\": true }, \"has2\": { \"CORS3\": false, \"CORS4\": true } }\";"
var deserializedTicker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonInfo>(JSONstring);
```

Comment: Now I understand. That code works. I try to get a hang of all the scenarios. So it is not an array as I thought it was but an object. So I do follow how you set up the code so nicely. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You json was incorrect, the key `has` contains a dict no list.

You need change your deserialize to dictionary or change your json.

Here you can see an example:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#array

Comment: Yes I tried to do an approach using dynamic and object. I did edit my post adding this approach but some error happens there also.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, `has` is an object, not an array. You should model your class to support an object containing the attributes `CORS`, `CORS2`, and so on, and so forth.

Edit: If you want to stick to `has` being an array, you should change your JSON to match what an array expects, which could be like: `has: [ false, true ]`, and omit the CORS thing.